# Why can´t i use a pre-defined variable for the pygame rect function?

Tags: python, pygame

Can anyone explain why this doesn´t work?
Is there a way to make this work or is it just not possible to give the pygame rect function a pre-defined variable with the required arguments?

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 600))
blue = (0, 0, 255)

x = (win, blue, (0, 510, 1200, 190))

pygame.draw.rect(x)
```

Every time I try the code, it says that the `rect` function needs at least 3 arguments.

Comment: unzip `pygame.draw.rect(*x)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to call `rect` with three arguments coming from x, as opposed to one argument which happens to be made up of 3 things, you can do:

```
pygame.rect( *x )
```